# hook_quicktabs_alter() is not called when using two quickstabs on the same page

Tags: blocks

I have embedded a second quicktab on page, which is called from the first quicktab (using qtabs as tab type).

The function hook_quicktabs_alter() is only called for the first quicktab, not for the second quicktab.

Any ideas?

Comment: I also have this issue. Would love to see a solution